# ASP.Net Literal possible inside Hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this text data from SQL reader which being retrieved thru Literal

`<asp:Literal ID="CliNox" runat="server"></asp:Literal>`

Now I need to make this a URL which redirect to another page for further info. So I tried it using `<a href>` tag:

`<a href="Contact.aspx"><asp:Literal ID="CliNox" runat="server">< /asp:Literal></a>`

The redirection works but the problem is I have to pass the text value of that Literal to the destination page. How can I achieve that? Is it capable of calling a C# method using a OnClick tag inside `<a href>`? I read that I should be using Hyperlink tag instead but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: The `{}` symbol in the question editor is for escaping code snippets (especially HTML). Please use that rather than adding spaces to your tags.

Comment: How about generate the complete link in server & then sent to client? (for ex. `Contact.aspx?key=value`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try this instead of using `Hyperlink`

Markup

```
<asp:Literal ID="CliNox" runat="server" />
```

C#

```
var textFromSQL = ...
CliNox.Text = string.Format("<a href='Contact.aspx?myQueryString={0}'>{0}</a>", textFromSQL);
```

Notice that if the `textFromSQL` contains `space` or other illegal characters, you need to normalize that & pass as third params to `sting.Format`, something like this:

```
var textFromSQL = ...
var normilizedText = textFromSQL.Replace(" ", "-"); // just for demo, you need to replace all illegal characters here
CliNox.Text = string.Format("<a href='Contact.aspx?myQueryString={0}'>{1}</a>", normilizedText, textFromSQL);
```

Comment: @theo glad to help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can consider using a **HyperLink** server control where you can specify your URL in its `NavigateUrl` property.

**ASPX markup**

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" Text="MyLink" />
```

**Code behind (Page_Load event)**

```
// assuming Contact.aspx is under the root folder of your application
// p is the query string parameter where the value from Literal.Text can be passed along and it's Url encoded as well.
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/Contact.aspx?p={0}", Server.UrlEncode(CliNox.Text));
```

Comment: There is no force to write this code within `Page_Load` event.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani As i mentioned in the post, it's just one of alternatives. The assignment of URL can be done in other event handlers.